# Camel 2.10 and Spring JAXB complaining about Handling Interfaces

Tags: spring, apache-camel, jaxb2, java

We recently upgraded the version of Open JDK 7 to version 1.7.0_u21 and have started to run into issues with Camel and JAXB that is included in that version.   Versions starting with 1.7.0_u9 or below seem to work as expected.   We are running things in an OSGi container and the JAXB-API is version 2.2.7, and the JAXB-IMPL is pulled from the JDK.   Any body else run into this problem if so any idea how to resolve it?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
this problem is related to the following location:
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor
at public org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.getBeanPostProcessor()
at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean

at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:212) ~[jaxb-api_2.2.7.jar:na]
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:146) ~[jaxb-api_2.2.7.jar:na]
... 159 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 39 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:91) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:451) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:283) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:126) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1148) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:130) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:221) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:186) ~[jaxb-api_2.2.7.jar:na]
... 160 common frames omitted
```

Update: A little more information, if I run with an Oracle JDK 7, everything seems to work as expected.  However, we need to use Open JDK 7 so would be nice to see if there is a fix besides trying random Open JDKs to see what works.